# What does %= mean in Java?

Tags: java, variable-assignment, operator-keyword, modulus

How does %= work in Java? I've been told that it can be used to reassign a value?

Grateful if anyone could teach! Thanks!

```
minutes=0;
while(true){
minutes++;
minutes%=60;
}
```

Comment: In Java, binary operators (`op`) in expressions of the form `x = x op y` can be written as `x op= y`. Thus `minutes %= 60` is equivalent to `minutes = minutes % 60`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is short for:

```
minutes = minutes % 60;
```

There are other, similar [*compound assignment operators*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.26.2) for all the binary operators in Java: `+=`, `-=`, `*=`, `^=`, `||=`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

+= is add to:

```
i+=2;
```

is `i = i + 2;`

`%` is remainder: `126 % 10` is 6.

Extending this logic, `%=` is set to remainder:

```
minutes%=60;
```

sets minutes to `minutes % 60`, which is the remainder when `minutes` is divided by 60. This is to keep minutes from overflowing past 59.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [Modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) which is the same as taking the remainder from division. `minutes%=60;` is the same as `minutes = minutes % 60;` which is the same as `minutes = minutes - (((int) (minutes/60)) * 60);`